# Confusion with NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

```
 1.  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:VIPassetCount forKey:@"VIPcount"];
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

 2.   `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:VIPassetCount forKey:@"VIPcount"];`
```

I am confusing wheather i need to use 'synchronise' when dealing with NSUserDefault.Because I don.t find any difference between using or non using it('synchronise').please explain with two code given above.

Comment: Well it's all in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html): _Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes._

Comment: @Alladinian you should put this comment in answer

Answer (score 2):

Just read the  **[documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**

> NSUserDefaults caches the information to avoid having to open the user’s defaults database each time you need a default value.
>
> The synchronize method, which is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, keeps the in-memory cache in sync with a user’s defaults database.

So unless you are in a special case where you *need* the values to be actually written on disk, you don't need to use `synchronize` because the system will do it for you when needed.

Answer (score 0):

when you are going to update the value of NSUserDefaults you need to use:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

**saving data**

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:@"xxxxxxxx" forKey:@"name"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

The purpose of **[default synchronize]**; is to make the user defaults get written on disk immediately. You don't need to call it explicitly, iOS already does it at appropriate moments (like when going into background). So you can remove that line. In fact, it's a performance problem if you call synchronize every time you set a default.